# Rear Ended someone who was ticketed for not having a valid license?

Tags: united-states, liability, driving, utah

I rear ended someone who was ticketed for not having a valid license.  Am I responsible for paying for the damage on his car?  I was also ticketed for the rear-end.

Comment: I would suppose that yes, you are liable.

Comment: Yes, of course. One has nothing to do with the other.

Comment: @closetnoc Although you're probably right, the fact that the other driver had no valid license (which is a moving violation, or even a crime, in many jurisdictions) might be "evidence" of contributory negligence, i.e., the reason they did not have a license was also a factor in causing the accident. Obviously, the simple fact of having the valid license in your possession doesn't make you a safer driver, and not having a license does not inherently imply you are an unsafe driver.

Comment: @Upnorth. The fact that the other driver did not have a valid license does not absolve you of the responsibility of maintaining a safe distance when driving. No judge would accept it as an argument. And I do not think any attorney would have the nerve either. You cannot link the fact that the invalid license as an indication of safe driving. Especially in light of the responsibility of maintaining of a safe distance. However, some states do recognize the legal excuse of other factors such as being cut off then suddenly stopping. Something along those lines could work.

Comment: @clostetnoc I certainly didn't say it "absolves" anyone of anything. I suggested it might be worth looking into WHY the person "did not have a valid license". Maybe if they have a history of being involved in similar collisions, it can be used against them.  Contributory negligence is a thing. For all we know, the "rear end" of the other vehicle came at the OP's vehicle while he was completely stopped.

Answer (score 2):

> Am I responsible for paying for the damage on his car?

Yes, if you were deemed at fault in the accident. Does the citation you got state that you were at fault in the accident? If so, you are liable for the damage.

If you were at fault in the accident and for the damages, this is an issue between your insurance company and the other drivers' company, and has nothing to do with the fact that the other driver did not have a valid license. (But it could very well be an issue for the other driver and *their own* insurance company).

Comment: If the other driver had no license there's a good chance that there is no other insurance company.

Comment: True, but I didn't want to speculate too much. (At the same time, if the OP had liability or comprehensive.)

Comment: Many states have laws that provide a rebuttable presumption that a driver who "rear-ends" another vehicle is automatically at fault (following too closely, driving too fast for conditions, failure to use due care, etc).  Whether the other vehicle was also being driven unsafely may be a factor, but not having a valid license doesn't automatically make the driver less safe. The *reason* for not having a valid license, however, may be relevant to contributory liability.